# Using pandas functions with Pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, bigdata, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to rewrite my Python script (Pandas) with Pyspark, but I can't find a way to apply my Pandas functions in a way to be more efficient with Pyspark functions:

my functions are the following:

```py
def decompose_id(id_flight):
    
    my_id=id_flight.split("_")
    Esn=my_id[0]
    Year=my_id[3][0:4]
    Month=my_id[3][4:6]

return Esn, Year, Month

def reverse_string(string):
  stringlength=len(string) # calculate length of the list
  slicedString=string[stringlength::-1] # slicing 
  return slicedString
```

I would like to apply the first function to a column of a dataframe (in Pandas I get a row of three elements)
The second functions is used when a condition of a column of a DataFrame is verified

is there a method to apply them using Pyspark dataframes?

Comment: Pandas and Spark are not working the same way. Please explain with sample input and output what you want to do. Forget about your pandas function, explain the expected behavior.

Comment: btw, `reverse_string` should simply be `def reverse_string(string):return string[::-1]`. And `string` is the name of a builtin lib, better use another word, like `in_string` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply these functions as UDF to a Spark column, but it is not very efficient.

Here are the functions you need to perform your task :

- [`reverse`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.reverse) : use it to replace your function `reverse_string`
- [`split`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split) : Use is to replace `my_id=id_flight.split("_")`
- [`getItem`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.getItem) : use it to get the item in splitted list `my_id[3]`
- [`substr`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.substr) : to replace the slicing in python `[0:4]`

Just combine these spark functions to recreate the same behavior.

Comment: What do you mean by not very efficient? (are you pointing to spark performance?)

Comment: @f.ivy Running UDFs is a considerable performance problem in PySpark. When we run a UDF, Spark needs to serialize the data, transfer it from the Spark process to Python, deserialize it, run the function, serialize the result, move it back from Python process to Scala, and deserialize it.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification Steven

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to leverage pandas functionality one way would be to use - [Pandas API](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/pandas-function-apis.html) along with `groupBy`

It provides you a way to treat each of your `groupBy` sets as pandas dataframe on which you can implement your functions.

However since its Spark , schema enforcement is pretty man necessary as you will go through the examples provided in the link as well

An implementation example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62414109/ml-function-as-pyspark-udf)

**For Trivial Tasks , like reversing the string opt for inbuilt Spark Functions , else UDF's**